# Chrome extension only work if USB device connected?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, usb

I wrote a chrome extension that is intended to collaborate with a custom hardware device I designed. The problem is, the extension uses a key listener injects a script, but i only want the script to fire if the hardware is plugged in. Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming the device can be detected only from a content script, remove everything from the default script except the listener which will send an event to your non-persistent [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)'s onMessage listener that will run the full content script via chrome.tabs.executeScript.